# Most optimized way to organize blog category in MySQL & url mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been creating a blog and I'm unable to decide the best way to categorize the articles.

The current way I thought was best would be to include the category in the articles table which includes the following rows.

```
  articles structure
+----------------------+
| article_id           |
| article_title        |
| article_content      |
| article_category     |
+----------------------+
```

In each article where I write I'd include the article category. Example.

```
+------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
| article_id | article_title | article_content  | article_category |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1      | How do I....  | Want to know...  |      How-to      | 
|     2      | Learn faceb.. | Facebooks new... |  Social Network  | 
+------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+
```

and then use `if(isset($_GET['article_id']) && isset($_GET['article_category'])){ }` to retrieve both together, or would it be better to create a new table for the specific categories? an example below.

```
  categories structure
+-----------------+
| category_id     |
| category_title  |
| article_id      |
+-----------------+
```

and whenever I need to retrieve the articles based on categories I'd just use it from the categories table (**The categories structure above is just an example**)?

*Also if someone could spare another moment to answer a simple question I'd appreciate it. I'll be using the articles table above as an example with the information.*

instead of using the following to retrieve the articles,

`www.example.com/article.php?article_id=1&article_category=How-to`

I would like to display the article url as followed, could this be accomplished by using mod_rewrite or would I need to create folders in my server for it to be possible?

`www.example.com/How-to/How-do-i`

Does stackoverflow use mod_rewrite to do the following?

www.stackoverflow.com/questions/id/title?

Note: I know how to display the title in the url, all I've been wondering is about the rewriting.

*Thank you for your time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a regular **1:n relationship**. One article can have one category, one category can have multiple articles. This can be resolved with two different models where one holds an identifier of an element of the other model. Speaking in terms of SQL: You would have two tables where in `articles` you'd save the `category_id` (remember: one article one category, so this is a correct implementation).

```
  articles
+----------------------+
| article_id           |
| article_title        |
| article_content      |
| category_id          |
+----------------------+

  categories
+-----------------+
| category_id     |
| category_title  |
+-----------------+
```

This would usually be done using a [foreign key constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). Once done, SQL checks if an entry is valid (so an article cannot have a number for `category_id` that doesn't exist in table `categories`). Also this will allow you to specify, e.g. that once a category is deleted, all referencing articles shall be deleted as well, or not.

If you want one article to be able to have multiple categories, you are lookin for a **n:m relationship**. In SQL you create a third table

```
articles_categories
+-----------------+
| article_id      |
| category_id     |
+-----------------+
```

Both attributes build the primary key, each is a foreign key as well.

---

To your second question: Yes this can easily be done via mod_rewrite. There are lots of tutorials out there and it should be quite simple. SO probably uses this as well, but I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: I appreciate your time, all other answers were great and to the point. It's too bad I can only choose one best answer but I have found yours to be the most optimized version and close to what I thought was best, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using `pivot` tables.  This isn't some fancy datatype in MySQL, but just a concept of how to organize your data.  The idea is similar to a `Many To Many` relationship.  Where many articles have relationships with many categories.  This also allows you the flexibility of assigning more than one category to an article.  PHP frameworks like Laravel, make these sort of relationships a breeze.  Here's a basic overview.

**articles Table**

```
articles structure
+-----------------+
| id              |
| article_title   |
| article_content |
+-----------------+
```

**categories Table**

```
categories structure
+-----------------+
| id              |
| category_title  |
+-----------------+
```

Then you use a pivot table to have different relationships between articles and categories.

**categories_articles Table**

```
articles_categories structure
+-----------------+
| id              |
| article_id     |
| category_id      |
+-----------------+
```

In this pivot table you can have multiple rows for the same article to indicate multiple categories for that article.  In the end, you'd do something like this.

```
<?php

$article = // Get the article you want, including it's id.

$categoryIds = // SELECT * FROM categories_articles WHERE article_id = $article['id']

$categories = // SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = (Each of the $categoryIds)
```

This is obviously psuedo code, and you can actually get this all done with a single SQL query, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

As for storing/getting the data from your database, a very straightforward approach would be to have three tables. The articles table will stay the same, but the categories table needs to have the article id dropped from it. The third table will map M:N relationships between the two, and looks like:

```
id   | article_id |  cat_id
---------------------------
```

When an article is saved with a category, a new entry will be put in this table (we'll call it articles_categories_map) to relate the two. When you want to retrieve all articles by category, the query will be thus:

```
SELECT `article_id` FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `articles_categories_map`
ON `articles`.`id`=`articles_categories`.`article_id` INNER JOIN `articles_categories` 
ON `articles_categories_map`.`category_id`=`articles_categories`.`id`
WHERE `articles_categories`.`title` = ""
```

Note: This approach will allow you to attach several categories to one article, and vice versa.

As for rewriting your URLs, mod_rewrite can certainly do this. You should take a little time investigating common approaches to this problem when using MVC. This will give you insight into how you might want your rules to be structured.

Cheers